# Proper Python SelectionSort

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to learn the selection sort using python, but can't get my code to work. Some assistance would be appreciated.

```
def selection(seq):
    for x in range(len(seq)):
    temp = 0
        for y in range(1, len(seq)):
            if seq[y] < seq[temp]:
            temp = y
    if temp != 0:    
        seq[x], seq[temp] = seq[temp], seq[x]
    return seq
```

selection([12, 38, 2, 18, 15, 1, 19])

Comment: What is the problem about this code?

Comment: It's not correct.

Comment: How is it not correct?

Comment: I know what is the specific problem?

Comment: It isn't performing the sort properly. I am trying to figure out why my code is not correct and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: pls fix the code indentation and put here an example input & *output* you're getting now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed indexes for both loops and initialisation of temp. You can fix it with this code:

```
def selection(seq):
    for x in range(len(seq)):
        temp = x
        for y in range(x+1, len(seq)):
            if seq[y] < seq[temp]:
                temp = y
        seq[x], seq[temp] = seq[temp], seq[x]
    return seq

seq = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
print(selection(seq))
```